Type 'false' has no call signatures. (tsserver 2349)
I am getting a Typescript warning for the following:
let d: { [key: string]: { [k: string]: boolean } | number[] } = {
  blah: [],
};
d["blah"].push(2);

The warning:
 This expression is not callable.                                               
 Not all constituents of type 'boolean | ((...items: number[]) => number)'    
 are callable.                                                                  
 Type 'false' has no call signatures. (tsserver 2349)  

The code works and if I console.log(d['blah']) I get [2]. Why am I getting the warning? How do I correct it (or ignore it)?
My tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

I tried printing to the console and the code works so am confused why the warning if it works

According to your typescript interface you defined key can be either an array of number or an object.
So you should first check if d['blah'] is an array then push the value
interface IObjectType {
  [key: string]: {
    [k: string]: boolean
  } | number[]
}


let d: IObjectType = {
  blah: [],
};
if (Array.isArray(d['blah'])) {
  d["blah"].push(2);
}

